# Oberserve to attributes of Object with 2 Oberservers

Tags: java, observable

I got a product object with two attributes which I want to oberserve with two different oberservers. But if I only change one attribute I also get a notification from the other attribute observer that it got changed. How can I make sure to only get a notification when it really got changed?

```
import java.util.Observable;
public class Product extends Observable {

        private String name;
        private double price;


        public void setName(String n){
            name = n;
            this.setChanged ();
            this.notifyObservers();
        }

        public void setPrice(double p){
            price = p;
            this.setChanged ();
            this.notifyObservers();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name; 
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price; 
        }
    }

public class ObserverDemo {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.addObserver((obj, arg) -> System.out.println("Name was changed to: " + ((Product) obj).getName()+"\n"));
        p1.addObserver((ob, arg) -> System.out.println("Price was changed to: " + ((Product) ob).getPrice()+"\n"));


        p1.setPrice(1.95);
        p1.setName("Milk");


        p1.setName("Banana");
        p1.setPrice(0.95);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any change on the observable class will notify all the registered observer classes. You can use the argument in the notifyObservers method to identify the change and create only one observer object.

```
import java.util.Observable;
public class Product extends Observable {

    private String name;
    private double price;


    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
        this.setChanged ();
        this.notifyObservers("Name was changed to " + n + "\n");
    }

    public void setPrice(double p){
        price = p;
        this.setChanged ();
        this.notifyObservers("Price was changed to " + p + "\n");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name; 
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price; 
    }
}

public class ObserverDemo {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.addObserver((obj, arg) -> System.out.println(arg));

        p1.setPrice(1.95);
        p1.setName("Milk");

        p1.setName("Banana");
        p1.setPrice(0.95);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats what I thought of first, but I am supposed to do it with 2 observers. I have absolutely no idea how to solve that..